# Algebra 101: Making subject

Tags: factoring

I am trying to figure out how the upper equation can be equivalent to the one at the bottom.

[image]

My best guess is that something is being multiplied or divided from both sides but cannot figure out what.

I proceed as follows:

I first expand everything and cancel out similar terms to ensure that I have L+W on one side and I get the following:

$$ rL(\rho-1)>= -{\sigma}{\tau}(L+W)$$

So isolating L+W gets a very different result.

I'd really appreciate if anyone can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: make the substitutions $W+L\equiv u$ and $L=u-W$ , then solve for $u$

Comment: By the way these are called *inequalities,* not equations.

Answer (score -1):

Continuing from where you left off, plus assuming $1 \gt \rho \implies 1 - \rho \gt 0$, $L + W \gt 0$ and $1-\frac{\sigma\tau}{r(1-\rho)} \gt 0$, gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
rL(\rho-1) & \ge -\sigma\tau(L+W) \\
-\frac{rL(1 - \rho)}{L+W} & \ge -\sigma\tau \\
-\frac{L}{L+W} & \ge -\frac{\sigma\tau}{r(1-\rho)} \\
1-\frac{L}{L+W} & \ge 1-\frac{\sigma\tau}{r(1-\rho)} \\
\frac{W}{L+W} & \ge 1-\frac{\sigma\tau}{r(1-\rho)} \\
W & \ge (L + W)\left(1-\frac{\sigma\tau}{r(1-\rho)}\right) \\
\frac{W}{1-\frac{\sigma\tau}{r(1-\rho)}} & \ge L+W \\
L + W & \le \frac{W}{1-(\sigma\tau)/(r(1-\rho))}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Comment: Indeed, the parameters are described in the same manner. In line 3, how did you get the negative sign on LHS?

Comment: @user508281 In line $3$, the negative sign comes from it was using $\rho - 1 = -(1 - \rho)$ and I divided by $1 - \rho$. I will update my answer in line $2$ to make this a bit more clear.